# How to skip() a question not a section in swirl? follow up to " R: Trouble in swirl when using && "

Tags: r, swirl

I am having the same swirl issue as @markerbrecht(R: Trouble in swirl when using &&).

Thanks to @Daniel Miller I get why the && is no longer working in the latest version, but I still don't understand why skip() doesn't seem to work in swirl for example:

```
> TRUE && c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
Error in TRUE && c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE) : 
  'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
> 
> 
> skip()
Error in TRUE && c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE) : 
  'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

| Leaving swirl now. Type swirl() to resume.
```

I looked up `skip()` in swirl in 3 ways and got three definitions:

Rstudio cursor highlight: 'return to main menu'
`?skip()`: 'Skip the current unit of instruction.'
but the recommended (and the most obvious for novices like me) help menu below...
`info()` menu in swirl defines it as : 'allows you to skip the current question'.

```
When you are at the R prompt (>):
| -- Typing skip() allows you to skip the current question.
| -- Typing play() lets you experiment with R on your own; swirl will ignore what
| you do...
| -- UNTIL you type nxt() which will regain swirl's attention.
| -- Typing bye() causes swirl to exit. Your progress will be saved.
| -- Typing main() returns you to swirl's main menu.
| -- Typing info() displays these options again
```